# Internet Explorer: Disable “Do you want to open or save this file?” download prompt

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

I have a windows 8.1 and IE 11, i could not downgrade IE.
All i am trying to do is using VBA i am suppose to download a csv file.
As i do it i get a prompt that says "Internet Explorer: Disable “Do you want to open or save this file?” download prompt". 
I tried [these steps](http://9to5it.com/internet-explorer-disable-do-you-want-to-open-or-save-this-file-prompt/). But it still gives me the same prompt. Please let me know if this could be solved using a different setting.

Comment: Balaji,let me know if the your issue is resolved. I am also facing the same issue. I have tried all the links that are present across sites.

Comment: I need to disable this feature as well. Zero workable information on the internet